# How does Laravel defer multiple bindings all listed in a single service provider?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, service-provider, deferred-loading

I want all my repositories to be listed in a single service provider, but I **don't** want them all loaded at once...

Consider the service provider below:

```
class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = true;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            'App\Repositories\Contracts\FooRepository',
            'App\Repositories\SQL\FooSQLRepository');

        $this->app->bind(
            'App\Repositories\Contracts\BarRepository',
            'App\Repositories\SQL\BarSQLRepository');

        // and more to be added later...
    }

    public function provides()
    {

        // Will it defer and load all these at once? Or only the one(s) needed?
        return ['App\Repositories\Contracts\FooRepository',
                'App\Repositories\Contracts\BarRepository'];
    }

}
```

[According to the Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/master/providers#deferred-providers), I can defer the registration of bindings until needed. But does this work for when I've added multiple bindings in a single service provider? Specifically I mean, will it defer and then load **all** or load **only the one needed**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel will register all bindings, even if only one is needed. The deferred feature actually works pretty simple. First, a map of the entries in `provides()` and the actual provider is created:

`Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository@compileManifest`

```
if ($instance->isDeferred())
{
    foreach ($instance->provides() as $service)
    {
        $manifest['deferred'][$service] = $provider;
    }
    $manifest['when'][$provider] = $instance->when();
}
```

Then when `make()` is called in `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`...

```
if (isset($this->deferredServices[$abstract]))
{
    $this->loadDeferredProvider($abstract);
}
```

...and the binding matches one of a deferred provider it will end up here:

`Illuminate\Foundation\Application@registerDeferredProvider`

```
$this->register($instance = new $provider($this));

if ( ! $this->booted)
{
    $this->booting(function() use ($instance)
    {
        $this->bootProvider($instance);
    });
}
```

As you might are able to tell, now the provider is registered as usual which means `register()` and `boot()` is called. If you think about it, it's not even possible to load one binding from a service provider and not include the other ones, because it's all done in one method.

Comment: This answer makes me sad, because now I need to create a service provider for each repository (since I don't want to load all of them at the same time)

Comment: I'm in exactly the same situation. It would be great if there were a flag on the bind method. Maybe time for a PR :)